# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.register(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)V

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, maven-2

I have checked my project dependency and found the required class exists in xmlsec-1.5.8.jar and that is already included. Also from the dependency structure,i see it is not being overridden by any lower version. Still i am una ble to find the reason behing this exception. I am running spring boot 2.0.5
Can you please help me resolve the below issue -

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.register(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)V
```

### Dependency Tree

```
INFO] com.myproject.microservice:UserIDPasswordUpdate:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.34:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.34:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.34:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.11:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.11:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.197:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.billdesk:billdesk:jar:1.0:system
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.wss:xws-security:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.crypto:xmldsig:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security-saml:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-profile-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-core:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     +- org.cryptacular:cryptacular:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.54:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- net.shibboleth.utilities:java-support:jar:7.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.geronimo.javamail:geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail:jar:1.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-policy:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.6.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.5.1-1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:compile
[INFO] |           \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]       +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.10-b140310.1920:compile
[INFO]       \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.10-b140310.1920:compile
```

### POM.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.billdesk</groupId>
            <artifactId>billdesk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/billdeskenc-1.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-common -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId> <artifactId>wss4j-ws-security-common</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.3</version> </dependency> -->


        <!-- -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
            <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/axis/axis-jaxrpc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- excluding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- excluding -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-security/xmlsec -->



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.cxf
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            cxf-codegen-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [${org.apache.cxf.version},)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>

                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>


                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdls/AccountInquiry.wsdl</wsdl>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Looks like it's the register method (or the method invocation?) it's moaning about, rather than the class?

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/46485860/2224047

Comment: checked that answer closely.. but it couldn’t help.. the error seems very direct.. but i’m not able to find out why

Comment: thank you guys for looking into the issue. :) I have updated the question with a solution i found for my issue.

Comment: Suggest you move the solution into an answer (it is fine to answer your own question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for the above mentioned issue and it was due to conflicting dependency issue. Incorporating several maven dependency for several issues or development was the reason behind is. What i finally did is declaring the cxf version on top of all other related dependency and referring that cxf version for all the related dependencies and finally worked!

```
<properties>
            <cxf.version>2.7.14</cxf.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>

        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```