# NoSuchMethodError: What version of Apache Xml Security do I need?

Tags: java, wss4j

I was getting this exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.utils.XMLUtils.decode
```

Then I updated my dependencies and moved on to another similar exception which I am unable to resolve for quite a while:

I am getting NoSuchMethodError when my module receives the request upon calling this method

```
WebServiceTemplate client = ...;
client.marshalSendAndReceive(req, new ActionCallback("http://samples/RequestOrder"));
```

it throws

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.encryption.AbstractSerializer: method <init>()V not found
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.StaxSerializer.<init>(StaxSerializer.java:62)
```

the (at least I think) relevant part of my dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

I was looking at multiple versions of `org.apache.xml.security.encryption` and it doesn't look like any of those versions have such method. Any idea what would be the correct combination of versions?

as a sidenote I also found this library and thought that would be helpful , but it seems it is somewhat different than aforementioned `<groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue and tried possible solutions online but to no avail.
Some of the documents suggested that dependency mismatch with other dependencies is key, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46488690/6153860).

In relation to this exact reported error, I kept on changing the version of the below dependency and finally reached this, which was the latest version as at the time this answer was posted.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But remember to ensure that if you have the below dependency, exclude that of xmlsec :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```